# maxcommittokeep value=1 configuration in solr

Tags: solr, lucene

```
<str name="maxCommitsToKeep">1</str>
```

For what this field is used . What happens if we increase the value of this key.Can someone help me on this.

Comment: its part of the deletion policy...The policy has sub-parameters for the maximum number of commits to keep (maxCommitsToKeep), the maximum number of optimized commits to keep (maxOptimizedCommitsToKeep), and the maximum age of any commit to keep (maxCommitAge),

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Its part of the deletion policy.

The policy has sub-parameters for the maximum number of commits to keep (`maxCommitsToKeep`), the maximum number of optimized commits to keep (`maxOptimizedCommitsToKeep`), and the maximum age of any commit to keep (`maxCommitAge`).

```
<reopenReaders>true</reopenReaders>
<deletionPolicy class="solr.SolrDeletionPolicy">
  <str name="maxCommitsToKeep">1</str>
  <str name="maxOptimizedCommitsToKeep">0</str>
  <str name="maxCommitAge">1DAY</str>
</deletionPolicy>
<infoStream>false</infoStream>
```

For more information, please check the [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/indexconfig-in-solrconfig.html)